# How do I have Google not index any of my site, except my domain?

Tags: search, google, robots.txt

```
Disallow: /
```

I want Google to index the index page, but nothing else. Will this achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should specify on Index page as follows:-

```
<meta name="Robots" content="INDEX, FOLLOW" />
```

For other page, mention as follows:-

```
<meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
```

Comment: what if, let's say, the pages are not in HTML?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: As far as I know, this is common concept should be followed for all the type of pages. Main settings should be done on **Robot.txt**

Comment: @thephp all your *pages* are HTML. If you are talking about indexable files like images or PDFs then you'll need to add those to robots.txt. Put them in a subfolder and block those folders.

Answer (score 0):

> **Robots.txt**

The correct way to block all search engines is using a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file, a simple text file placed in the root of your webserver containing the following code:-

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This works for all files on your webserver rather than a spesific page like the metatag mentioned in @SivaCharan's answer.

> **mod_rewrite and htaccess**

Since not all spiders abide by the robots.txt protocol, you might also want to block a spesific crawler from your site if it is showing up in your server logs after being blocked in robots.txt.

You can achieve this using the `.htaccess file` and `mod_rewrite` Here's an example for blocking Baidu and Sogou spiders:

Add the following to the .htaccess file:-

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider [NC,OR” 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Sogou
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F”
```

This only applies to a **single domain** rather than the entire webserver.

> **httpd.conf**

If you have access to the httpd.conf you can add block a spesfic crawler from the **whole server** by listing the User Agent header fields there.

Include your new directives in the following section of Apache's httpd.conf file:

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#

... 
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Baiduspider" bad_bots
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Sogou" bad_bots
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "212\.100\.254\.105" bad_bot

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

Deny from env=bad_bots
```